# Creating and manipulating three dimensional matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication, bsxfun

I'm desperately trying to avoid a `for` loop in Matlab, but I cannot figure out how to do it. Here's the situation:

I have two `m x n` matrices `A` and `B` and two vectors `v` and `w` of length `d`. I want to outer multiply `A` and `v` so that I get an `m x n x d` matrix where the `(i,j,k)` entry is `A_(i,j) * v_k`, and similarly for `B` and `w`.

Afterward, I want to add the resulting `m x n x d` matrices, and then take the `mean` along the last dimension to get back an `m x n` matrix.

I'm pretty sure I could handle the latter part, but the first part has me completely stuck. I tried using `bsxfun` to no avail. Anyone know an efficient way to do this? Thanks very much!

**EDIT:** This revision comes after the three great answers below. gnovice has the best answer to the question I asked without a doubt. However,the question that I meant to ask involves squaring each entry before taking the mean. I forgot to mention this part originally. Given this annoyance, both of the other answers work well, but the clever trick of doing algebra before coding doesn't help this time. Thanks for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Even though the problem in the question has been updated, an algebraic approach can still be used to simplify matters. You still don't have to bother with 3-D matrices. Your result is just going to be this:

```
output = mean(v.^2).*A.^2 + 2.*mean(v.*w).*A.*B + mean(w.^2).*B.^2;
```

If your matrices and vectors are large, this solution will give you much better performance due to the reduced amount of memory required as compared to solutions using [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) or [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html).

**Explanation:**

Assuming `M` is the m-by-n-by-d matrix that you get as a result before taking the mean along the third dimension, this is what a span along the third dimension will contain:

```
M(i,j,:) = A(i,j).*v + B(i,j).*w;
```

In other words, the vector `v` scaled by `A(i,j)` plus the vector `w` scaled by `B(i,j)`. And this is what you get when you apply an element-wise squaring:

```
M(i,j,:).^2 = (A(i,j).*v + B(i,j).*w).^2;
            = (A(i,j).*v).^2 + ...
              2.*A(i,j).*B(i,j).*v.*w + ...
              (B(i,j).*w).^2;
```

Now, when you take the mean across the third dimension, the result for each element `output(i,j)` will be the following:

```
output(i,j) = mean(M(i,j,:).^2);
            = mean((A(i,j).*v).^2 + ...
                   2.*A(i,j).*B(i,j).*v.*w + ...
                   (B(i,j).*w).^2);
            = sum((A(i,j).*v).^2 + ...
                  2.*A(i,j).*B(i,j).*v.*w + ...
                  (B(i,j).*w).^2)/d;
            = sum((A(i,j).*v).^2)/d + ...
              sum(2.*A(i,j).*B(i,j).*v.*w)/d + ...
              sum((B(i,j).*w).^2)/d;
            = A(i,j).^2.*mean(v.^2) + ...
              2.*A(i,j).*B(i,j).*mean(v.*w) + ...
              B(i,j).^2.*mean(w.^2);
```

Comment: @gnovice:  I think OP wants to first add the resulting matrices and then take the mean.  So taking the mean of each of the vectors independently isn't going to do it.

Comment: @Lambdageek: Actually, in this case it does. The code above gives the same result as the more complicated set of steps in your answer. I'll add an explanation.

Comment: @gnovice Hm. Yes you're right. Since A and B participate essentially as scalars, your assertion follows just by thinking about `sum` instead of `mean`.  Going to delete my answer.  Better to do this algebraically.

Comment: @gnovice: Thanks. I was so focused on the step I couldn't do, that it didn't occur to me to work the algebra through to the end. Nice.

Comment: @gnovice: Sadly, the but I left out is that I have to do one more operation before taking the mean that doesn't commute, so I need to know how to do the matrix conversion after all. Still, a great answer, but I'm accepting the `repmat` solution.

Comment: @PengOne, I undeleted my `bsxfun` answer.  Might be better because it only uses `bsxfun` and `reshape` which do not require replication as `repmat` may.

Comment: @PengOne: It turns out you *can* still use an algebraic approach even with the squaring operation included, and it will likely give you *much* better performance.

Comment: @gnovice: Thanks again for pointing out that math makes things easier. You can have your check mark back. This let's me crank up the sizes a fair bit farther.

Answer (score 1):

Try reshaping the vectors `v` and `w` to be `1 x 1 x d`:

```
  mean (bsxfun(@times, A, reshape(v, 1, 1, [])) ...
        + bsxfun(@times, B, reshape(w, 1, 1, [])), 3)
```

Here I am using `[]` in the argument to `reshape` to tell it to fill that dimension in based on the product of all the other dimensions and the total number of elements in the vector.

Comment: This is faster and a bit cleaner. I need to square each entry before taking the mean, and this method allows me to do this easily. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use `repmat` to tile the matrix in the third dimension.

```
A =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6

>> repmat(A, [1 1  10])

ans(:,:,1) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6


ans(:,:,2) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

You still don't have to resort to any explicit loops or indirect looping using `bsxfun` *et al*. for your updated requirements. You can achieve what you want by a simple vectorized solution as follows

```
output = reshape(mean((v(:)*A(:)'+w(:)*B(:)').^2),size(A));
```

Since OP only says that `v` and `w` are vectors of length `d`, the above solution should work for both row and column vectors. If they are known to be column vectors, `v(:)` can be replaced by `v` and likewise for `w`.

---

You can check if this matches [Lambdageek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362716/creating-and-manipulating-three-dimensional-matrices-in-matlab/6362881#6362881) (modified to square the terms) as follows

```
outputLG = mean ((bsxfun(@times, A, reshape(v, 1, 1, [])) ...
        + bsxfun(@times, B, reshape(w, 1, 1, []))).^2, 3);

isequal(output,outputLG)

ans =

     1
```

Comment: @PengOne: I had assumed `v` and `w` were column vectors (since you only mention that it is of length `d`). So perhaps you have row vectors, in which case, please try `v(:)*A(:)'` and similarly for `w`. I'll edit my answer to include this.

Comment: @yoda: transposing `v` did the trick. This works as well. Thanks!

Comment: @PengOne: No problem :) Just out of curiosity, what are the sizes of your matrices and vectors?

Comment: @yoda About 10K by 10K, though not square. Ideally they should be 1M by 1M (again, not exactly square), but the for loop is too slow even for 10K. This should speed things up, though.

Comment: @PengOne: 1M by 1M?? That's insane. What's the size of `d`?

Comment: @yoda I know :-( Luckily `d` is much for sensible... around 7K.